# How to set different credentials of ethereum accounts for doing transactions in smart contract? For a blockchain based voting system

Tags: flutter, dart, blockchain, ethereum, ganache

I'm implementing a **Smart voting system using ethereum blockchain** and using **Ganache**. As per the system, the election authority will authorize the people by using their public addresses in the blockchain. And then only they will be able to vote.

But the problem is, as per my code , every voting transaction is done by a single blockchain account, because it always gets the same credentials derived from the same private key.

**What i want to do is, for each authorized voter, i want the app, to change the credentials to that particular voter's credentials of their blockchain account. So the voting transaction will be done by the relevant particular account.** Is there a way to retrieve the credentials of each person. Or to change credentials for each logged in account?  i'm struggling to do it.

It is a flutter app.

Here is my code, where i set the credentials for the transaction.

```
 Future<String> authorize() async {
    var addressone =
        EthereumAddress.fromHex("0xc347C739ae787a0D9A182efDa9055FAe109F055C");
    var response = await submit("authorize", [addressone]);
    print("deposited");
    return response;
  }

  Future<String> vote() async {
    final addressone =
        EthereumAddress.fromHex("0xc347C739ae787a0D9A182efDa9055FAe109F055C");
    var candidate = BigInt.from(1);
    var response = await submit("vote", [addressone, candidate]);
    print("voted");
    return response;
  }

  Future<String> submit(String functionName, List<dynamic> args) async {
    EthPrivateKey credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(
        "968499dbee4f8b8491d9d0e02ff631347291a41e33dc95033c70758a2e99657b");
    DeployedContract contract = await loadContract();
    final ethfunction = contract.function(functionName);
    final result = await ethclient.sendTransaction(
        credentials,
        Transaction.callContract(
            contract: contract, function: ethfunction, parameters: args),
        fetchChainIdFromNetworkId: true);
    return result;
  }
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? :(

Answer (score 1):

> for each authorized voter, i want the app, to change the credentials to that particular voter's credentials of their blockchain account.

You can program any kind of rules for your voting smart contract using Solidity programming language. This includes how voting rights are distributed. However "how to create a smart contract based voting system" is too wide topic for StackOveflow answer, more of a material for University course or very long online tutorial.